# web-sites that are not protected by SSL

Tags: ssl, security

Is there a way to configure browser or computer, so it gives a user a warning or will not let to open any web-sites that are not protected by SSL?

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for a user side. I am as user would like to stay away or be protected from unsure logins on web-page without SSL. Is there a way to set my browser or computer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Secure Socket Layer (SSL) warnings, used in web browsers to indicate a problem with a web page's certificate or the potential for a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack, are ineffective.

My recommendation would be to configure the website, in case you are developing it, to FORCE SSL when someone tries to access the website without SSL.

E.g. If someone is visiting http://www.mywebsite.com then force redirect that individual to

Have a look at the following video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEV3HOuM_Vw

Fabio @fcerullo

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it only works [assuming that there is no MITM](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628), unless the browser is pre-loaded with this site in its HSTS list.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent traffic that's not going to 443/TCP or if you have 'better' techniques at the host/network egress, decide traffic is not encrypted and drop it. Browser wise, maybe a plugin could help, but you'll likely want to do this at a layer past just the browser to ensure this policy is followed.